# Not able to save gstream videosink

Tags: gstreamer

I'm just trying to save the dummy video to my directory.
In that case I end up in this error so I knew something is wrong in the pipeline.

Do I missing any parameters here ?

gst-launch -v videotestsrc ! ximagesink ! filesink location=~/cupcake.mp4
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link ximagesink0 to filesink0

I just want to record only the video.

Answer (score 2):

ximagesink is a sink element and as such doesn't have an output (source pad).
This command will tell you about the details of an element:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 ximagesink
```

Notice that ximagesink has only sink pad and no source pads, so it doesn't generate any output.

You can dump the video directly to file by using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! filesink location=~/cupcake.raw
```

Unfortunately, this is still not what you want as videotestsrc will generate raw video and not encoded or muxed to mp4. If you want mp4 you need to put it into the mp4mux that will organize the data it receives into the mp4 container. It is also recommended to encode the video to reduce its size. Let's assume you want to use H.264 as your codec. You can use the element x264enc to encode to H.264

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=~/cupcake.mp4
```

Notice that I also added the "-e" parameter that will make gst-launch-1.0 send an EOS event and wait for the EOS message to indicate elements have finished working. Without the flag the pipeline is simply interrupted and aborted.

In any case I'd recommend going back to the manuals for application development: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/
The manpage for gst-launch-1.0 is also useful.

**Disclaimer:** You are using gstreamer 0.10 which is 3 years unmantained and obsolete, please upgrade to 1.0 (This answer is aimed at 1.0 but it can easily be applied to 0.10 by changing the commands to 0.10 version)

Comment: Thanks indeed for the answer, actually I can able to record the video in *mp4 format in my host machine. When I tried this similar command on my OMPA target, I got ffenc pacakage missing but I tried to install sudo-apt get ffmeg, still not able to install any video encoder. $ gst-launch videotestsrc num-buffers=100  ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=~/pattern.mp4

Comment: Try installing gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks. I just found out other encoder which works in my target.. problem solved... D_D